# загрузка и распаковка архивов в c#

Tags: c#

У меня есть программа на с, которая загружает документы ворд, а затем нужное содержимое документа раскидывает по таблице DataGridView.
Теперь нужно, чтобы загружались не только документы Word, но и архивные файлы, различных форматов. Из этих файлов  также автоматически выгружались вордовские документы и также распределялись по таблице. 
Подскажите пожалуйста идею, будьте так добры!!

Comment: Какая идея вам нужна? Архив надо распаковывать, файлы из него открывать и обрабатывать.

Comment: Ну как вообще работать с архивом. Программно. Как я понимаю, подключать библиотеки и начинать работу. Но у меня, кроме как простого архиватора ничего не получается. А нужно, чтобы архивы загружались также, как и вордовские документы и все разносили по столбцам.

Comment: как работать с архивом - зависит от вида архива и, соответственно, библиотеки, которая предоставляет интерфейс работы с архивом

Comment: Ну мне нужно, чтобы все виды архивов работали ( и zip, и rar, и exe). И  если только там содержатся документы Word, то тогда выгружал их. У меня тут море библиотек и  Ionic.Zip, и System.IO.Compression, и  SharpCompress, SharpZipLib. Но когда я создаю даже простой архиватор, то с форматом .rar не загружаются. Наверное и для него нужно соответственную библиотеку подключить?

Comment: @Яна Естественно. Как вариант - иметь хотя бы консольные утилиты для распаковки. В вашем коде - формировать командную строку, для распаковки архива в заданную папку. Потом, программно смотрим эту папку, если там есть .doc - загружаем, ничего подобного нет - не загружаем, ну и, соответственно после всего этого, очищаем временную папку

Comment: А программно как осуществить? Хотя бы в общих чертах, пожалуйста =) а библиотеку какую лучше подключить, чтобы все форматы читал?!

Comment: Я сомневаюсь, что есть универсальные мультиформатные библиотеки. Т.к. у каждого архива, если вы понимаете, может быть разный алгоритм упаковки. Ну и второе, вот как возможно сказать, как это программно осуществить, если у каждой библиотеки могут быть свои интерфейсы, и работать с ними, соответственно вы будете по-разному.

Comment: File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, (byte[])Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(res.Key)); - Вот так извлекаем во временную папку?

Comment: это что вы делаете? достаете что-то из ресурсов (почему это все в ресурсах?) и записываете бинарник в какой-то файл??? Вы в целом имеете представление о том, что вы делаете и как должен выглядеть процесс??? Это раз. Во вторых, мне кажется это обсуждение уже выходит за рамки данного сайта. Ну и три, у меня достаточно своего кода, или вы хотите, чтобы я сел и объяснял какие-то элементарные вещи? ) Четыре - ну есть же гугл и гитхаб и книги в конце-концов.

Comment: Не, все форматы читать не получится хотя бы потому, что нет полного и окончательного списка форматов. Вам придётся добавлять поддержку форматов по одному. Есть библиотеки, наподобие 7-zip, которые поддерживают _несколько_ форматов, но конечно не _все_.

Comment: SharpCompress rar поддерживает https://github.com/adamhathcock/sharpcompress/blob/master/FORMATS.md

Comment: @VladD а можно хотя бы один пример формата, который все еще встречается, но не поддерживается 7-zip на чтение? Мне правда интересно, т.к. до сих пор не попадалось ни чего, что этот монстр не смог бы сожрать.

Comment: @rdorn: Вроде он не умеет .ha (был когда-то такой формат)

Comment: Хотя да, 7-zip — хороший выбор.